Getting Fields in FormData in Remix React
How do we get the fields without having to do this individually?
const name = (formData.get("name") ?? "") as string;
Can we map or iterate it?
CODE
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
    request,
}: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    const name = (formData.get("name") ?? "") as string;
    const website_url = (formData.get("website_url") ?? "") as string;
    const user_id = (formData.get("user_id") ?? "") as string;

    try {
        // call api here

        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        throw json({ error: "Error" }, { status: 500 });
    }
};


You can use Object.fromEntries() static method and pass your formData object to it it will convert standarad js object.
Object.fromEntries(formData);



const formData = new FormData();
formData.set("name","Jhon");
formData.set("age","30");
console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData));




the type of name, website and user_id is FormDataValueEntry, I needed it to be a string

You can assert  something like this Object.fromEntries(formData) as {
[k: string]: string;
};
